# How to add bootstrap JSON content into a html file in Play Framework?

Tags: json, backbone.js, playframework

In the Application.java I get all users

```
public static void index() {
    renderArgs.put("users", Users.getAll()); //getAll() returns gson.JsonArray
}
```

In index.html I bootstrap this users like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Users.reset(&{users});
</script>
```

But the JSON is rendered like this:

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1234&quot; ...
```

**How can I get the JSON to be formated as JSON?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       Users.reset(&{users.raw()});
    </script>
```

**From playframework documentation:**

[**raw()**](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/javaextensions#raw)

Returns the object without template escaping.

Returns: play.templates.Template.ExecutableTemplate.RawData.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Backbone.js, they recommend you to use this style of bootstrapping your collection(s). I didn't really like this approach though, so I used an alternative: to bootstrap your `Collection`s, simply wrap them in a manual [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) call to initialize them. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON("@{controllers.MyJsonApiController.getStuff()}", function(data) {
            Users.reset(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

*Note:* the exact syntax of the `Users.reset()` call may not be correct, you may have to define the collection in the `window` scope, depending on your requirements.

An even better approach I found — when you're also using the Backbone.js `View`s — is to encapsulate your `Collection` management in your `View` objects. This way, when you render your page, the only thing you have to do is render the view and this will do its own initialization.

*Update:* corrected the `fetch()` call to a `reset(data)` call.